# Check ReCaptcha on landing page, and redirect to main

Tags: php, security, recaptcha

I'm implementing Re-captcha on a landing page, and on successful authentication only does the user gets the access to the main page.

In the code below i have implemented an html form that has a reCaptcha, and gets redirected to verify.php. This checks the validity of the reCaptcha, and if true - displays the HTML content (i want the reCaptcha to appear everytime the user enters this page).

I'd like to know if this is a secure enough way, or are there any 'major' loopholes that can break in.
Any suggestions and recommendations will be highly appreciated!  Many thanks!

(BTW StackOverflow uses something similar to check on non-logged in users https://stackoverflow.com/captcha)

Html Code ->

```
<form action="verify.php" method="POST" class="popup-form">

  <br>

  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="SITE KEY"></div>

  <input type="submit" value="Enter" name="thesubmit">
</form>
```

Verify.php ->

```
  <?php

                  $captcha;

                  if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
                    $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

                  if(!$captcha){
                    echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
                    header( "Location: http://www.example.com/index.php" );
                    exit;
                  }
                  $response=json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=MY SECRET KEY &response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), true);
                  if($response['success'] == false)
                  {
                    echo '<h2>Authentication Failed :/</h2>';
                     header( "Location: http://www.example.com/index.php" );
                     exit;
                  }
                  if($response['success'] == true)
                  {

                    ?>
                    <html>
                    <head>
                      <title>My site</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                    <h1>Display all the content which needs to be displayed here</h1>
                    </body>
                    </html>


                    <?php
                  }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Google uses the expired callback to let you know when the recaptcha has expired and is no longer valid. I'm using the `setTimeout` as a quick and dirty way to observe changes, namely the value of `doRedirect`. Initial when this code runs, `doRedirect` is `false`, so you need to find out when and if it changes.

You have to use the reCaptcha verify response call back. Something like this: `<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=reCaptchaCallback&render=explicit'></script>`

```
var timer = 0,
    RC2KEY = 'sitekey',
    MAIN = 'http://main.page/',
    doRedirect = false;

function reCaptchaVerify(response) {
    if (response === document.querySelector('.g-recaptcha-response').value) {
        doRedirect = true;
    }
}

function reCaptchaExpired () {
    /* do something when it expires */
}

function reCaptchaCallback () {
    grecaptcha.render('id', {
        'sitekey': RC2KEY,
        'callback': reCaptchaVerify,
        'expired-callback': reCaptchaExpired
    });
}

timer = setTimeout(function(){
    if (doRedirect) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        location.href = MAIN;
    }
},0);
```

Comment: colecmc, thanks for the reply. I didn't understand about expired-callback and the timeout, could you explain please? I have updated my code btw..cheers!

Comment: If this answer is correct, please mark it as such. I have updated my answer to explain a bit further.

Comment: The current code i have did not use your answer, colecmc, so i can't mark is as correct. And i still don't understand it well, i'm new. But i will give it an upvote. If you could answer my updated question, i would be happy to accept your answer :) Thanks

Comment: Well this solution was on the way to help a lot of people- It was viewed 2000 times, but it was not accepted- A lot of people would vote it up but me personally, i would like more clarification as to where the function reCaptchaCallback () is called- i have no idea how to implement your code although i believe it is good.

Comment: @AlbuquerqueWebDesign, reCaptchaCallback is called by Google when reCaptcha is loaded. `<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=reCaptchaCallback&render=explicit'></script>`